# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos de una consulta en un archivo PDF?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, formularios, fpdf

Estoy intentando obtener los datos que me genera una consulta en el archivo PDF, no sé como hacerlo por eso solicito la ayuda acá, quisiera que los datos que me da la consulta al undir el botón PDF me abra el archivo PDF con esos datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CÓDIGO DE BÚSQUEDA Y CONSULTA**

```html
<?php
 $TIPO_BUSQUEDA = $_POST["TIPO_BUSQUEDA"];
    function ejecuta_consulta($labusqueda)
    {
        include("conexiond.php");

        $conexion= mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Fallo al conectar con la base de datos";
            exit();
        }

        mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die("No se encuentra la base de datos.");


        $consulta = "SELECT datosbasicos.CED_PAC,datosbasicos.NOM_PAC,datosbasicos.APE_PAC,datosbasicos.SEX_PAC,datosmedicos.COD_CONSULTA,datosmedicos.ALT_PAC,datosmedicos.PESO_PAC,datosmedicos.FECHA,datosmedicos.TIPO_CONSULTA,datosmedicos.SINTOMAS,datosmedicos.OBSERV,datosmedicos.HIS_PAC,datosmedicos.MEDI_PAC,datosmedicos.OPERADO,datosmedicos.ALERGIAS FROM datosbasicos INNER JOIN datosmedicos ON datosbasicos.CED_PAC=datosmedicos.CED_PAC WHERE datosbasicos.NOM_PAC LIKE '$labusqueda' OR datosbasicos.CED_PAC LIKE '$labusqueda' OR datosmedicos.COD_CONSULTA LIKE '%$labusqueda%' OR datosbasicos.CED_PAC LIKE '$labusqueda' OR datosmedicos.FECHA LIKE '$labusqueda'  ";

        $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

        $filas = array(); // Crea la variable $filas y se le asigna un array vacío
        // (Si la consulta no devuelve ningún resultado, la función por lo menos va a retornar un array vacío)

        while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $filas[] = $fila; // Añade el array $fila al final de $filas
        }

        mysqli_close($conexion);

        return $filas; // Devuelve el array $filas
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sistema de historias médicas - Dr. Darling Davila</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $mibusqueda=$_GET["buscar"];

        $mipag=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

        if ($mibusqueda!=null) {
            $pacientes = ejecuta_consulta($mibusqueda);
    ?>

        <div id="main-container">
        <img src='imagenes/header.png' class='img'>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Codigo</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Cedula</th>
                        <th>Nombres</th>
                        <th>Apellidos</th>
                        <th>Sexo</th>
                        <th>Altura</th>
                        <th>Peso</th>
                        <th>Sintomas</th>
                        <th>Observaciones</th>
                        <th>Tipo de consulta</th>
                        <th>Medicamentos actuales</th>
                        <th>Alergias</th>
                        <th>Operado</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    // Si la variable $pacientes esta definida y no está vacía
                    if (isset($pacientes) && !empty($pacientes)) {
                        // Recorre cada $paciente dentro del array $pacientes
                        foreach ($pacientes as $paciente) {
                            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['COD_CONSULTA'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['FECHA'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['CED_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['NOM_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['APE_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['SEX_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['ALT_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['PESO_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['SINTOMAS'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['OBSERV'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['TIPO_CONSULTA'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['MEDI_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['ALERGIAS'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['OPERADO'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    } ?>
                </tbody>
        </div>
        <div>
        <form name="reporte" action="database.php" method="post">
        <input type='submit' name='generar' value='PDF' class='text-center inline-block col-md-12 espacio-arriba btn-enviar2'>
        </form>
        </div>
    <?php
        } else {
            echo("<form action='". $mipag . "' method='GET'>
                <img src='imagenes/header.png'>
                    <h2>Busqueda de paciente</h2>
                    <div class='contenedor'>
                    <select name='TIPO_BUSQUEDA' class='input-100 text-center col-md-12'>
      <option value='Cedula' selected='selected' <?PHP if($TIPO_BUSQUEDA=='Cedula'){ echo 'selected='selected'; } ?> Cedula</option>
       <option value='Edad' <?PHP if($TIPO_BUSQUEDA=='Edad'){ echo 'selected='selected'; } ?> Edad</option>
           <option value='Nombre' <?PHP if($TIPO_BUSQUEDA=='Nombre'){ echo 'selected='selected'; } ? >Nombre</option>
           <option value='Fecha' <?PHP if($TIPO_BUSQUEDA=='Fecha'){ echo 'selected='selected'; } ?> Fecha</option>
     </select>
                    <input type='text' name='buscar' class='input-100 text-center inline-block col-md-6 btn-enviar espacio-arriba'></label>

                    <input type='submit' name='enviando' value='Consulta' class='text-center inline-block col-md-12 espacio-arriba btn-enviar'>
                </div>
                </form>");
        }
     ?>

</body>

</html>
```

**ESTE ES MI DOCUMENTO DE GENERAR EL PDF:** Actualmente solo lo tengo para que haga consulta a la BD en general, lo quiero para que se genere en mi consulta.

```html
<?php
require('tfpdf.php');
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345678');
mysqli_select_db($con,'pacientes');


class PDF extends TFPDF {
 function Header(){
  $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
  
  //dummy cell to put logo
  //$this->Cell(12,0,'',0,0);
  //is equivalent to:
  $this->Cell(12);
  
  //put logo
  $this->Image('imagenes/header.png',150,10,60);
  
  $this->Cell(1,50,'Lista de pacientes',0,1);
  
  //dummy cell to give line spacing
  //$this->Cell(0,5,'',0,1);
  //is equivalent to:
  $this->Ln(5);
  $this->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
  
  $this->SetFillColor(54,150,129);
  $this->SetDrawColor(36,99,85);
  $this->Cell(40,5,'Nombre ',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(40,5,'Apellido',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(25,5,'Edad',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(25,5,'Sexo',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(30,5,'Telefono',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(30,5,'Celular',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(130,5,'Direccion',1,1,'',true);

  
 }
 function Footer(){
  //add table's bottom line
  $this->Cell(190,0,'','T',1,'',true);
  
  //Go to 1.5 cm from bottom
  $this->SetY(-15);
    
  $this->SetFont('Arial','',8);
  
  //width = 0 means the cell is extended up to the right margin
  $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo()." / {pages}",0,0,'C');
 }
}


//A4 width : 219mm
//default margin : 10mm each side
//writable horizontal : 219-(10*2)=189mm


$pdf = new PDF('L','mm',array(400,200)); //use new class

//define new alias for total page numbers
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,15);
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(36,99,85);

// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
$pdf->AddFont('Arial','','Arial.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);

$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from datosbasicos");
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
 $pdf->Cell(40,5,$data['NOM_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(40,5,$data['APE_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['EDAD_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['SEX_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(30,5,$data['TEL_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(30,5,$data['CEL_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(130,5,$data['DIR_PAC'],'LR',0);
 
 if($pdf->GetStringWidth($data['email']) > 65){
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',7);
  $pdf->Cell(65,5,$data['email'],'LR',0);
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
 }else{
  $pdf->Cell(65,5,$data['email'],'LR',0);
 }
 $pdf->Cell(60,5,$data['address'],'LR',1);
}

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

y tienes que hacer en tu HTML un form para que solicite el pdf a la pagina.php que genera el pdf.

```
<form name=’pdf’ method=’post’ action=’paginaquegeneraelPDF.php’>
<input type=’submit’ value=’Generar’ />
```

```html
<?php
require('tfpdf.php');
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345678');
mysqli_select_db($con,'pacientes');


class PDF extends TFPDF {
 function Header(){
  $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
  
  //dummy cell to put logo
  //$this->Cell(12,0,'',0,0);
  //is equivalent to:
  $this->Cell(12);
  
  //put logo
  $this->Image('imagenes/header.png',150,10,60);
  
  $this->Cell(1,50,'Lista de pacientes',0,1);
  
  //dummy cell to give line spacing
  //$this->Cell(0,5,'',0,1);
  //is equivalent to:
  $this->Ln(5);
  $this->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
  
  $this->SetFillColor(54,150,129);
  $this->SetDrawColor(36,99,85);
  $this->Cell(40,5,'Nombre ',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(40,5,'Apellido',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(25,5,'Edad',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(25,5,'Sexo',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(30,5,'Telefono',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(30,5,'Celular',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(130,5,'Direccion',1,1,'',true);

  
 }
 function Footer(){
  //add table's bottom line
  $this->Cell(190,0,'','T',1,'',true);
  
  //Go to 1.5 cm from bottom
  $this->SetY(-15);
    
  $this->SetFont('Arial','',8);
  
  //width = 0 means the cell is extended up to the right margin
  $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo()." / {pages}",0,0,'C');
 }
}


//A4 width : 219mm
//default margin : 10mm each side
//writable horizontal : 219-(10*2)=189mm


$pdf = new PDF('L','mm',array(400,200)); //use new class

//define new alias for total page numbers
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,15);
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(36,99,85);

// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
$pdf->AddFont('Arial','','Arial.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);

$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from datosbasicos");
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
 $pdf->Cell(40,5,$data['NOM_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(40,5,$data['APE_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['EDAD_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['SEX_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(30,5,$data['TEL_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(30,5,$data['CEL_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(130,5,$data['DIR_PAC'],'LR',0);
 
 if($pdf->GetStringWidth($data['email']) > 65){
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',7);
  $pdf->Cell(65,5,$data['email'],'LR',0);
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
 }else{
  $pdf->Cell(65,5,$data['email'],'LR',0);
 }
 $pdf->Cell(60,5,$data['address'],'LR',1);
}

    $pdf->Output("prueba.pdf",'F');
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.open('prueba.pdf','_self','');</script>"; 

exit;

?>
```

cuando creas el pdf suponiendo que todo esta bien, lo unico que tienes que hacer es mostrar el PDF con las instrucciones que te coloque al final.

Comment: Me esta arrojando un error en esta linea, he intentando acomodarlo pero no me deja ¿Sabras cual es el **;** Que esta fallando ? 

`echo “<script language=’javascript’>window.open(‘prueba.pdf’,’_self’,”);    </script>”;//paral archivo pdf generado`

Comment: echo "<script language='javascript'>window.open('prueba.pdf','_self,'');    </script>";//paral archivo pdf generado    prueba asi, le cambie las comillas @PabloPernia

Comment: Estoy probandolo, ahora la pagina se queda en blanco, una consulta Luis ¿Pero en el documento que genera el PDF donde esta haciendo el llamado para imprimir los datos que ya me arrojo la busqueda anterior?, ¿Tengoq ue cambiar algo de esta linea? 

`$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from datosbasicos");`

Comment: puedes usar la misma consulta que haces para la busqueda en la pagina que genera el pdf,  puedes ver un ejemplo [aqui](https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/1501-dise%C3%B1o-de-reportes-en-pdf-con-fpdf-y-php/) y lo otro que se me ocurre que puedes hacer es usar el plugin de jquery-datatables para exportar la tabla: [aqui mas info](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export) @PabloPernia